# Show post thumbnail only if it exists using timthumb

Tags: theme-development, php, themes, post-thumbnails

I am using timthumb as the image size management script throughout my wordpress site but I just noticed that an empty image tag shows up even when there is no thumbnail.

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()):
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
?>
    <div class="wp-caption alignright">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $src[0]; ?>&w=145&h=80&q=100&zc=1" height="80" width="145" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="wp-post-image" />
        <p class="wp-caption-text"><?php the_post_thumbnail_caption(); ?></p>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am doing it this way because I wanna show the caption whenever it exists. I also tried doing it all in php. I never do it like this, so I'm not sure if it's correct but It also shows the same thing and also echos the template_url before the image.

```
<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()){
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');
    echo '<div class="wp-caption alignright">
        <img src="'. bloginfo('template_url') .'/scripts/timthumb.php?src='. $src[0] .'&w=145&h=80&q=100&zc=1" height="80" width="145" alt="'. the_title() .'" class="wp-post-image" />
        <p class="wp-caption-text">'. the_post_thumbnail_caption() .'</p>
    </div>';
} ?>
```

Am I doing something wrong here. That img tag is inside the condition right? Still a broken image place holder is showing up with every post. *Image below*

[image: broken image placeholder]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code.

Thanks!

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Were did you use your code? Directly in the single and loop template files? I've (more or less) the same code as u and its working as expected. Offtopic: You could use `add_image_size('handler', 100, 50)` to register your desired image sizes and set the same handler in `wp_get_attachment_image_src($postId, 'handler')` to display it. No need for timthumb here.

Comment: What Roman said. There is absolutely no need to use TimThumb in this context. (@Roman you should make that an answer, to explain how to use the core functionality in order to accomplish what the OP wants.)

Comment: I know about the core functions but it doesn't absolutely crop the image the way I want. I always want width 145 and height 80.

Comment: Oh and the main thing, I forgot: I've got the first code in my index loop file.

Comment: @Aayush `add_image_size` has also crop-functionality. Set the last parameter to `true` will force to crop the image. However, check the answer below. On my local install the thumbnail is only displayed if a featured image is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented above, you don't have to use TimThumb at all to get additional image sizes for your uploaded images.

WordPress ships with the [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) function.

```
// functions.php
add_action('init', 'wpse26655_add_additional_image_sizes');
function wpse26655_add_additional_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size('thumb200x120', 200, 120, true);
}
```

In your template files, you could than query your thumbnail with your desired image size. E.g.

```
<?php
// single.php / loop-content.php

$thumbId = get_post_thumbnail_id();

if($thumbId) :
    $thumbSrc =  wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbId , 'thumb200x120');
    $thumbUrl = $thumbSrc[0];
    $thumbWidth = $thumbSrc[1];
    $thumbHeight = $thumbSrc[2];
?>

<div class="post-thumbnail">
    <img src="<?php echo $thumbUrl; ?>" width="<?php echo $thumbWidth; ?>" height="<?php echo $thumbHeight; ?>" />
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

### Note:

The additional images sizes are generated on image upload. If you want new sizes for existing images inside your medialibray, you have to recreate all thumbnail images. A very good plugin for this purpose is [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

Comment: Timthumb officially gone. Thanks for that. A lot cleaner code now, but the root problem remains. Still empty img tags.

Comment: Question answered. It was imported content from my online site without the imported media.

Sorry for wasting your time. I did learn stuff though.

Thanks!